# A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Building of my android app failed with a new strange set of errors:

theapp/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/out/com/comTest/theapp/databinding/TabPinBinding.java:48: error: illegal '.'
public final com.comTest.theapp..utilsviews.MyTextView pin8;

The class MyTextView is defined in theapp/utils/views/MyTextView.kt
it looks like the generator of java code makes a mistake.

As this code is right in generated java, I don't know how to correct the error or where to begin with to fix the problem.

The application compiled fine then I did the following:

- created a scratch.kt file where I needed to import some file defined in the utils folder
- updated some stuff (gradle pluggin, targetSDK value, remove redundant dependencies) following suggestion of android-studio. It was the usual stuff when updating android-studio internals.

the errors appear in the file TabPinBinding.java which start with:
"// Generated by view binder compiler. Do not edit!"

Answer (score 0):

I find the error.
It comes from a layout not used anymore in the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.comTest.theapp..utilsviews.PinTab
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pin_lock_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.comTest.theapp..utilsviews.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/pin_lock_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_margin"
            android:text="@string/enter_pin"/>
    <!-- other fields -->
</com.comTest.theapp..utilsviews.PinTab>
```

I do not know why the layout uses a wrong path to access the Layout class defined in the project but I suspect a bug of the IDE when propagating changes related to renaming or moving of the Layout class file.
This change was made a long time ago, and gradle and android studio seemed to have ignored the problem so far. Why it pops up now ?
I have updated the kotlin version to Java 8 (sourceCompatibility "1.83) and other changes. It looks that many problems are poping up...

To find the problem I made a search on the entire project with the string `com.comTest.theapp..utilsviews`

To remove the problem, I corrected the paths in the layout to : `com.comTest.theapp.utils.views` wherever the error occured.